# how to use a json function for filling combo box with database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, database, combobox

I am new at html and trying to relation between database.And i want to fill box with database

I have a code like

```
<div class="content" data-role="content" id="content" >
         <div id="car">
            <select name="selectCar" class="span12" id="Options" >
            <option value="-1">Bir istasyon seçiniz.</option>
            <option value="1">Mimarlık</option>
            <option value="2">Yurtlar</option>
            <option value="3">Bilgisayar Mühendisliği</option>
            <option value="4">Kimya Mühendisliği</option>
            <option value="5">Rektörlük</option>
            </select>           
         </div>
         <div id="cinfo"></div>

        <button onclick="javascript:callCarInfo.call(this,document.getElementById('Options').value);">Call Podcar</button>

      </div>
```

here

```
            <option value="1">Mimarlık</option>
            <option value="2">Yurtlar</option>
            <option value="3">Bilgisayar Mühendisliği</option>
            <option value="4">Kimya Mühendisliği</option>
            <option value="5">Rektörlük</option>
```

i want to fill this values and names of stations with database

I also have a station function which is

```
function getStationList()
{
    $db = new DBManager();
    $mysqli = $db->db_connect();

    $query = "SELECT stationId FROM Station";

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $list = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $list[] = $row['stationId'];
    }

    return json_encode($list);
}
```

I tried to use ajax function but i couldnt do it which is

```
$.ajax({
    url:'Stations.php',
    type:'POST',
    data: 'q=' + str,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( json ) {
        $.each(json, function(i, value) {
            $('#myselect').append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', value));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: .append($('<option>') should be .append($('<option></option>'). According to your code, if you want to fill the select named "selectCar", then it should be : $('#Options').append($('<option></option>'). Rest seems ok.

Comment: But where should i call the function to fill this ? i mean where and how to call getStationList() ..

Comment: Sorry i mean that where and how should i call

function getStation() which has $.ajax( { url: ....

Comment: ok I posted an example, hope thats helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS (page.html):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url:'Stations.php',
    type:'POST',
    data: 'q=' + str, // not sure you need that as you are not filtering on server side
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( json ) {
        $.each(json, function(i, value) {
            $('#myselect')
                  .append($('<option></option>', {text:value})
                  .attr('value', text);
        });
    }
  });
})
```

HTML (page.html):

```
<div class="content" data-role="content" id="content" >
         <div id="car">
            <select name="selectCar" class="span12" id="Options" ></select>           
         </div>
         <div id="cinfo"></div>
        <button onclick="javascript:callCarInfo.call(this,document.getElementById('Options').value);">Call Podcar</button>
</div>
```

Stations.php :

```
<?php
getStationList();
?>
```

Quick explanation : when page.html is loaded and ready, it makes an ajax call to Stations.php to get the list of Stations. On response, it iterates on results and add an option element for each result to the select element which have id "Options".

Comment: thank you for your answer it is working i think but this time i have a db problem :)